# VBA: Does Str(myString) do the same as Str(CDbl(myString))?

Tags: vba, ms-access, internationalization, type-conversion

**Question**: Can I assume that `Str(myString)` will always return the same result as `Str(CDbl(myString))` (assuming that `myString` is statically typed as a string)?

---

**Context**:
I am trying to understand VBA's implicit conversions. So far, it appears to me that `Str(myString)`

- implicitly parses `myString` into a double (*culture-sensitive*) and then
- converts the result into a *culture-insensitive* string.

For example, using a German locale (i.e. using `,` as the decimal separator), it holds that

```
" 1.2" = Str(1.2) = Str("1,2") = Str(CDbl("1,2"))
```

Since these implicit conversions contain a lot of "magic" to me, I am trying to rewrite a procedure that uses an implicit conversion (`Str(myString)`) to one using explicit conversion without changing the behavior.

Unfortunately, the documentation is wrong and, thus, useless. (The [documentation claims](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/str-function-HA001228913.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010131676) that the argument to `Str` is interpreted as a `Long`, which is obviously rubbish: If that were the case `Str(1.2)` could never yield `" 1.2"`.)

Comment: Just a comment to your "interpreted as a Long" is rubbish, statement. Perhaps it is not too well written, but I guess that it refers to the supported precision: long one is much higher than integer one (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y595sc15.aspx vs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/06bkb8w2(v=vs.90).aspx) and smaller than double one (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99xtshc.aspx). Thus the maximum value supported by this function is 9.2...E+18 (+ a decimal value), not 1.79..+308 of double.

Comment: @varocarbas: Interesting idea. However, I think that the Double precision is in fact larger than the Long precision: Double has [53 bits of precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (not counting the exponent), whereas Long is a 32-bit number in VBA.

Comment: This is what I said. "smaller than double one"... "maximum value supported by this function is 9.2...E+18 " (-> long maximum value) not 1.79..+308 of double

Comment: Ah I saw d-stroyer answer now. Str works fine with double precision? Then the MSDN article is completely wrong. I didn't test it. Same thing with your question (didn't read it properly and that's why I wrote a wrong reply) -> not something to be proud of, but the reality. While working on various things in parallel, saw your question and found it somehow peculiar: more or less generic question asking for something whose exact point is still not too clear to me. I am not justifying myself (I do apologise for my lack of care), just explaining why my interventions have been so inaccurate.

Comment: @varocarbas: Ah, yes, sorry, I misread your comment (confusing smaller and larger) -- guess we're even now. ;-) The exact point is the following: I have a procedure that uses `Str(myString)`, and I knew that there was some kind of implicit conversion of `myString` to some numeric value going on (before the *actual* work of Str kicks in). Since I don't like implicit conversions, I wanted to understand what happens so that I can replace it with an explicit conversion. PS: I *do* appreciate your interest in my question!

Comment: Ok. Everything clear now. Thanks for your kindness and sorry again for my attitude (After two months, I guess that I cannot use the "I am new here" excuse anymore :)).

Comment: @varocarbas: No apology needed. You tried to help and I appreciate that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is true. Str(x) and Str(Cdbl(x)) give identical result provided that x is String data type and contains a valid number.

I made a small test to get convinced.
I used Excel, but it holds the same with Access.

```
Public Function myStr(txt As String) As String
 myStr = Str(txt)
End Function

Public Function myStrCDbl(txt As String) As String
 myStrCDbl = Str(CDbl(txt))
End Function
```

I tried with some *key* values (0, 1.2, 1E+307, 1E-307, ...) : result of myStr and myStrCDbl are always identical.

I also agree with you that the documentation is wrong. If Str() argument would be interpreted as `Long`, then Str(1.2) would give "1", because `Long` is an integer type.

Comment: I agree. This `Debug.Print Evaluate(Str(1.2)), Evaluate(Str(CDbl("1.2")))` would do the same in one line (*provide your own parameters though*)

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time, I've found the [VBA language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851.aspx) and can confirm that the spec also answers the question with "yes":

- [CDbl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198992.aspx), when receiving a string, performs a ***Let***-coercion to Double:

> If the value of Expression is not an **Error** *data value* return the Double data value that is the result of Expression being **Let**-coerced to **Double**.

- [Str](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200152.aspx), when receiving a string, first performs a ***Let***-coercion to Double and then applies `Str`:

> [*If Number is a String,*] the returned value is the result of the Str function applied to the result of **Let**-coercing Number to **Double**.